# Extracting contents of unknown file format

Tags: decompilation, file-format, game-hacking, unknown-data

I would love some help on working with this file format.

I have this archived file from this abandonware game that I like to mess around with, and I have tried all sorts to try and expand it to extract the files from inside (They are .vag audio files).

I am lost on what to do from now on. I have tried using TrID but no result from it. I have also tried using software like WinRAR, 7-zip etc, which cannot recognise the file.

I do not think this is a known file extension since I have never seen it anywhere before, and the internet has no idea what it is when I try to search about it.

I'd also love to ideally create an extraction tool so I can extract content from other file types ending in this .xbd format.

I will really appreciate any help given, thank you :)

[.xbd file download (OneDrive)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiEcsvCdfJY5g-557PGxRmGtbWKpfw?e=RdfW0D)

Comment: I would suggest RE the game that load the file

Comment: @rce Apologies, the game is Midnight Club 2, published 2003. Inside the .xbd file I believe contains .vag files. This is in 'assets_p.dat' which is where the game files are. This is the link to the assets [link] (https://mega.nz/file/WVpHBK7K#XWjSZwxqdL4EdjXftVt91r96dad7JSXz97qsLr3N1cY) The xbd file is located in audio. If this still isn't enough info let me know,